# How to index one field Dates with a list of dates in Plone

Tags: python, plone

I want to create an event content type with one field Dates contains a list of dates (not recurring dates) and displayed in Plone like the official event content type.

I want to have one event that display many times in the portlet Calendar.

Is this possible and how (which addon to use, ...)

I'm currently trying MultiEvent addon (I have updated from Plone2.5 -> Plone4.1) but this addon need a cron to call an update method that change THE date to the next one.  So you can't see the event more than one time in the calendar.

It seems DateIndex can manage one date for one content. I'm looking for a Keyword Index but for dates.

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense, and I'm also a little puzzled. Frankly I'd have thought you have been using Plone long enough to know the answers to this already. :-) Questions: a) Whaddaya mean "many dates"? Just add date fields to the schema? b) What do you expect Plone to do with the extra dates? and c) date indexes only take one date each, but you can create more indexes for different fields; that's what the start and end indices are for. What do you expect the catalog to do for you?

Comment: Sorry @MartijnPieters I have written that question too fast. I have updated it, is it more comprehensive ?

Comment: It is, thanks; you want *one* index to index a *one* field that holds multiple dates. You'd also like the default calendar in Plone to display these events at multiple points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make your Event content a folderish, and insert date intervals inside it  (as another content type).

Retrieving them with catalog would look like:

```
catalog = getToolByName(context, 'portal_catalog')

catalog( object_provides=IMyDateInterval.__identifier__,
         sort_on='interval',
         interval={ 'query' : date_range, 'range' :'min:max'}
)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I really like the idea, simple and seems to work without much dev

Answer (score 0):

Would the DateRecurringIndex work for you?

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Products.DateRecurringIndex

Comment: I'm afraid not. recurring dates is not a list of dates. It's a definition (every month, every 2 weeks, ...) I'm in a different case, I want a list of dates. So a mix between DateIndex and KeywordIndex. Don't know if this exists